# What.. I am declaring @err_message but then too getting declare @err_message

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am declaring `@err_message` but then to getting declare `@err_message` like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_FONM_16_FILES
    (@COMMAND NVARCHAR (MAX),
     @DBNAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @FORMAT_TABLE NVARCHAR (MAX))
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF @COMMAND = N'HOMEOWNER'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ERR_MESSAGE VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL
        DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR (MAX)

        SET @SQL1 = N''+
    CONCAT('IF (SELECT MAX(DATA_TYPE) FROM  ', @FORMAT_TABLE ,')=', '''D''',' 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 100* FROM ', @FORMAT_TABLE , '
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
            SET  @ERR_MESSAGE= ''NOT AVAILABLE''
            RAISERROR(@ERR_MESSAGE, 16, 1)
    END'
    )

END
```

Run the procedure - I get this error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 51
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ERR_MESSAGE".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 52

Answer (score 4):

First, the fact that you need to resort to dynamic SQL because you need to execute the same query against different tables automatically smells like a bad database design.
It usually mean that you have more than one table for the same entity, and that these tables names contain a part that should be contained inside a column.

For instance, tables like `Payments_2016`, `Payments_2017` and `Payments_2018` - While there should be just a single table called `Payments` with a column called `Payement_Year`.

So the correct solution would probably be to refactor the database and change this kind of duplicate tables to a single table.

Having said that, I know a lot of people can't change the database design, so here is the solution to use in case you refactor the database:

You are declaring the `@ERR_MESSAGE` variable on the stored procedure, but you attempt to use it inside the dynamic SQL - and that runs inside a different scope and therefor has no access to the `@ERR_MESSAGE` declared on the stored procedure.

You can either declare it inside the dynamic SQL, or pass it to `sp_ExecuteSql` with proper parameters definitions.

You didn't show how you are running this SQL so it's kinda hard to give you a proper code example.

Also, you have `SELECT TOP 100*...` - you need a space between `100` and `*` - `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM`....

Comment: The T-SQL parser is oddly forgiving in some places. `select top 10*from sys.objects` executes without error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Really? I never would have though about attempting this... Good to know!

Comment: Only learnt this from learning about some SQL Injection attacks that got past "clever" sanitizers that thought that keywords would always be whitespace separated from other elements.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I receive  60 files per week from clients e.g client1 5 files , client2 10 files etc.. and after processing these files i have to insert records to production table.. so that's why doing dynamically per file so that i can track down if something goes wrong.. and Thank you so much.. Hope one day i can be a developer like you...

Answer (score 0):

Updated Query - Try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_FONM_16_FILES
(
    @COMMAND NVARCHAR (MAX)         ,
    @DBNAME NVARCHAR(MAX)           ,
    @FORMAT_TABLE NVARCHAR (MAX)    
)
AS 
BEGIN 
IF @COMMAND =N'HOMEOWNER'

BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR (MAX)

SET @SQL1=N''+
CONCAT('IF (SELECT MAX(DATA_TYPE) FROM  ', @FORMAT_TABLE ,')=', '''D''',' 
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 100 * FROM ', @FORMAT_TABLE , '
END
ELSE
BEGIN
        DECLARE @ERR_MESSAGE VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL
        SET  @ERR_MESSAGE= ''NOT AVAILABLE''
        RAISERROR(@ERR_MESSAGE, 16, 1)
END'
)

END
sp_ExecuteSql @SQL1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Zohar Peled. Also, I would rather be off dynamic SQL, and try a different approach that will fit your business. If not, I would focus on error handling as the current method you handled the error will give you a headache in the future. Imagine one of these tables have been changed, deleted, or corrupted. Do you believe that you'll know which table populated the error ? 
So, you might expand your current solution with more error handling or create your own solution for that matter.

Comment: While your last paragraph does have a very good point, your code is not scalable and repetitive.  In cases like this, I would rather keep the dynamic SQL if refactoring the database is impossible.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know the code is a repetitive, but it's just a short example without a dynamic sql (in case OP decided to go non-dynamic sql). Other than that, it depends on OP requirements and needs.

Comment: The fact that the code is repetitive is the smaller problem. The fact that it's not scalable is a much bigger problem. The common anti-pattern is to add these tables each X time - like in the payments example in my answer. This means that every time a new table added your stored procedure needs to grow as well. What happens after x * 10 time? or x *100? A dynamic SQL based solution will stay the same no matter how many tables will be added over time and that's it's main advantage over your proposed solution.

Comment: @ZoharPeled that's not a query issue (dynamic or non-dynamic) that's `a bad database design` (as you mentioned in your answer).

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware of this. However not every database can be refactored. Sometimes you are in too deep and can't change the database. Some people are working with 3rd party databases, some just don't have enough experience to properly design the database, and some does not have their boss's permission to do so. I'm sure there are plenty of other reasons why the database simply must stay ill-designed - I was referring to your proposed solution in case the database structure can't be changed.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I totally agree with you, it seems I didn't know that the OP tables could be expanded especially if is it controlled by 3rd party application or database. (even if we all still assuming this, I still think it's a good way to understand the outcomes from each direction).